# Get emails from Office 365 mailbox in PHP

Tags: php, email, exchangewebservices, office365

I want to list emails from an Exchange Office 365 mailbox. I saw on official documentation a Mail Rest API exist.

I tried `https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/OData/Me/Inbox/Messages` and it works. I can get my emails in JSON format.

But, I want to list like 10 different accounts, is there another solution ? Can I log to several accounts using this API ? Or should I use Imap (or POP3) connection ?

Comment: Why not doing the same thing 10 times if it works like this? I guess using IMAP wouldn't be more efficient in this case since you would also need to connect 10 times wouldn't you?

Comment: True, but because I didn't find anything on this method, I wanted any opinion. But I will do that, and see if it's efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Try `https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/OData/Users('user@example.com')/Inbox/Messages`. I'm not sure whether accessing other's mailboxes is supported through delegate access, Exchange Impersonation, or some other permission mechanism.

Found the information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn605896(v=office.15).aspx